# What are collections in .net 4.0

Tags: c#

Types of collections in .Net 4.0 .. 
How to implement ListDictionary in .Net 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the examples on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.listdictionary.aspx) not demonstrate `ListDictionary` usage?